# Appium with Python - setup class for webdriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, webdriver, appium, python-appium

Programing is a new thing for me and probably I am missing something obvious.

I would like to create a separate file and class for setup my webdriver for Appium tests, but I got errors like:

```
in test_login main_page = MainPage(self.driver)
AttributeError: 'test_Login_iOS' object has no attribute 'driver'
```

Currently I have two files: one with test case and other with methods for test steps:

1. test_Login_iOS.py:

   class test_Login_iOS(unittest.TestCase):

   def setUp(self):

   ```
   logging.info("WebDriver request initiated. Waiting for response, this may take a while.")

   # choose desired capabilities from desired_capabilities.py

   desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.desired_capabilities_for_iOS_iPad

   self.driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub", desired_capabilities)

   self.driver.implicitly_wait(15)  # seconds
   ```

   def test_login(self):

   ```
   logging.info("starting Test Case 1: login into active account")
   welcome_page = WelcomePage(self.driver)
   welcome_page.click_login_button()
   login_page = LoginPage(self.driver)
   ```

and second file, page_ios.py:

```
class BasePage(unittest.TestCase):
"""
:type driver: appium.webdriver.Remote
"""

def __init__(self, driver):

    super().__init__()
    self.driver = driver
```

When I add new test case I have to add to it the same setUp method like in previous test case, so I would like to create a new class "Setup" that could be shared across multiple test cases.

**Goal is to move setUp method to separate file and new class.**

Comment: I resolved that problem by adding additional method: 

`@classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):

     if cls is not SetupTestCase and cls.setUp is not     SetupTestCase.setUp:
            orig_set_up = cls.setUp

def set_up_override(self, *args, **kwargs):

            SetupTestCase.setUp(self)
            return orig_set_up(self, *args, **kwargs)
            cls.setUp = set_up_override`